# cannot be @Required or @NotNull

Tags: java, android-studio, realm

Al utilir la version  `4.3.3` de `REALM` para desarrollo android me arroja el siguiente error:

`Error:Field "groupName" with type "pizware.evaluapp.Models.Group" cannot be @Required or @NotNull.`

pero no utiizo ninguna de esas etiquetas para ningun campo. ¿Alguein sabe que esta pasando?

Comment: hola agrega tu clase!, donde tienes especificado el campo "groupname"? revisaste donde tienes las anotaciones @Required o @NotNull?

Answer (score 0):

La anotación `@Required` indica a Realm que aplique controles para rechazar valores nulos.

> Cuando se agrega a una RealmList de tipos primitivos  la anotación @Required, ejemplo:

```
RealmList <String>, RealmList <byte []>, RealmList <Boolean>, RealmList <Byte>,
 RealmList <Short>, RealmList <Integer>, RealmList <Long>, RealmList
 <Float>, RealmList <Double >, RealmList <Date>
```

> , esta no puede contener valores nulos.

[Revisa la documentación relacionada a la notación @Required.](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/Required.html)

---

Debes revisar en tus clases si estas agregando esta anotación, regularmente el problema es al definirla en alguna clase

```
 @Required 
 private MyClass myclase;
```